# É possível associar um Socket TCP a outro já conectado e enviar dados por ele?

Tags: c#, socket, redes

Quando eu uso `socket.Accept()` recebo um Socket conectado, usando a opção `socket.ExclusiveAddressUse = false` é possível associar (`Bind`) um outro Socket ao `EndPoint`.

Porém quando uso a função `ReceiveFrom` nesse segundo Socket recebo o erro:

> Uma solicitação de envio ou recebimento de dados não foi permitida
>   porque o soquete não está conectado e (durante o envio em um soquete
>   de datagrama usando-se uma chamada sendto) não foi fornecido um
>   endereço

Sei que isso é possível com UDP, seria também com TCP?

Como posso fazer isso funcionar?

O cliente:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.22.33"), 31));
socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Teste Socket"));
socket.Dispose();
```

O servidor:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.22.33"), 31));
socket.Listen(int.MaxValue);

Socket socket2 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket2.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
socket2.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 31));

byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];

var EPCliente = socket.Accept().RemoteEndPoint;
socket2.ReceiveFrom(buffer,SocketFlags.None,ref EPCliente);
socket.Dispose();
socket2.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
```

Comment: Para um socket TCP o método de receber dados seria Receive(), não ReceiveFrom(), este último serve para UDP e outros protocolos sem conexão pois você precisa receber o pacote e o remetente ao mesmp tempo, enquanto num socket TCP o lado remoto é definido e não muda.

Comment: Suspeitei, eu precisava ter uma referëncia para o socket de envio antes da conexão. De certo que internamente deve existir um token/ticket de conexão.
Acho esse modelo de soquete uma bagunça, pois se usa o mesmo objeto para diferentes protocolos/algorítmos/pilhas. Isso é má prática de orientação a objeto.

Comment: E esse `"0.0.0.0"` foi só um exemplo, não?

Comment: Acredito que a API siga as convenções BSD/Sockets, que tem esse mesmo caráter (usar recvfrom para UDP, recv pra TCP) e obviamente não é orientada a objeto.

Comment: Segundo o RFC 923 `0.0.0.0` significa `este host` o dot net interpreta como sendo `qualquer rede que esta máquina estiver conectada`.
Mas c# é orientada a objeto, é o tipo de coisa `legado` que se usa até hoje, e ninguém vai perder tempo refazendo algo que já funciona bem (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7moWY.jpg).

Comment: `0.0.0.0` é equivalente a `IPAddress.Any`